# Add a data-parsley-error-message attribute to a field using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, parsley.js

Due to my framework, I can't add parsley attributes in the HTML code.
So I have to **add them via javascript**.

I manage to add these ones:

```
var ccCode = $('#cc-code').parsley({
            required: true,
            type: 'number',
            length: '[3,4]',
            errormessage: 'Please enter a valid security code'
        });
```

But *'errormessage'* is not correct for the original parsley attribute (**data-parsley-error-message**).

How can I add it?

Answer (score 3):

Right, you're missing a capital 'M':

```
var ccCode = $('#cc-code').parsley({
        required: true,
        type: 'number',
        length: '[3,4]',
        errorMessage: 'Please enter a valid security code'
    });
```

Alternate solution is to set the options directly:

```
$('#cc-code').parsley().options.errorMessage = "Custom message";
```

Or multiple at a time:

```
$.merge($('#cc-code').parsley().options, {
  errorMessage: "Custom message",
  #...
}
```

Or via the attributes

```
$('#cc-code').attr('data-parsley-error-message', "Custom message here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to this problem.

```
var ccCode = $('#cc-code').parsley();

$('#cc-code').attr('data-parsley-error-message', "Custom message here");
```

This allows you to override the error message of parsley.js with javascript.